# Distinguishing key reuse in encryption algorithms

Tags: symmetric, key-reuse

Let $E$ be any encryption algorithm, and consider the following game capturing key reuse.

1. Alice samples a key $k$
2. Bob sends a set of messages $\{m_1, ...,m_n\}$ to Alice
3. Alice flips a coin

- if heads Alice encrypts all messages with $k$ and sends the ciphertexts to Bob,
- if tails, for each message $m_i$ she samples a key $k_i$ and sends $\{E_{enc}(k_i, m_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ to Bob.

4. Bob wins if he guesses the coin with probability higher than 0.5.

I am looking for security reductions to known properties, or some reference on how to approach this.

In particular, I am interested in the following generalization, where in step 1. Alice samples $k$ from a special set (for instance keys with low Hamming weight, symmetric crypto keys in a special byte format instead of uniformly random, etc).

Comment: If the protocol is non-interactive then the fact that a key should produce randomized ciphertext (indistinguishability) is already enough, isn't it? And I assume the adversary / Bob only wins if they can guess with higher than 0.5 probability, otherwise they can win by chance alone :)

Comment: Of course, prob. > 0.5, fixed.
Good point about it being non interactive.
What about the interactive case?

Comment: As there are no keys reused, and assuming that the sampling doesn't contain any weak keys, I guess that an adversary cannot create a distinguisher then either, but that assumes that the encryption algorithm is secure, of course (and it reads **any** encryption algorithm, which would possibly include weak ones (?)). To be honest, as it is stated, we cannot assume anything really and in that case any proof will also be worthless.